# HttpClient is throwing object reference not to set exception when calling rest api in .net MAUI app using Android Emulator. it works fine in WinUI

Tags: cross-platform, .net-maui

[![This is post request call.][Here it will call the API from the Mobile App]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O40yR.png)
[![This is Rest Client Constructor.][Here HttpClient is initialized and assigned]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHM4Z.png)

Comment: have you tried debug and figure out which line casue the error?